# MVC - POST запрос не проходит проверку в контроллере.

Tags: php, ajax, post, mvc, form

Написал MVC. В файле template_view есть форма, которая обрабатывается через .ajax. В файле ajax следующий код:

```
    $(function () {
    $('.targets').submit(() => {
        const formData = {
            'prev': $('input[name=prev]').val(),
            'curr': $('input[name=curr]').val(),
            'sum': $('input[name=sum]').val(),
            'uri': window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: '../application/controllers/controller_electricity.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: "param=" + JSON.stringify(formData),
            dataType: 'json',
            encode: true,
        })
            .done(data => {
                console.log(data);
            })
    });
})
```

Ajax передает POST запрос в controller элемента. Код контроллера ниже:

```
 <?php     
class Controller_Electricity extends Controller
{    
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->model = new Model_Electricity();       
    }    
    function action_index()
    {    
        $data = $this->model->get_data('electricity');
        if($_POST['param']){
            $this->model->set_data($_POST['param']);
        }
        $this->view->generate('electricity_view.php', 'template_view.php', $data);
  }
}
```

Не могу понять почему, но в контроллере фейлится проверка на прием POST запроса. 
action_index - это action который автоматически передается коутом, если не установлен никакой другой action в url.

Comment: а вардамп на $_POST че пишет?

Comment: null, хотя данные 100% в переменной formData в ajax файле есть. Через консоль проверял.

Comment: это если дампить $_POST['param'] - выходит null. Если дампить просто $_POST, то получаю 3 переменные: prev, curr, sum, Где uri делась - непонятно

Comment: потому что неправильно передаете, лучше же data= []; data.param = JSON.stringify(formData)

Comment: Извините, не совсем понял как это будет выглядеть.

Comment: внутри $.ajax не data: "param=", а data.param =

Comment: попробовал: data: 'data.param=' + JSON.stringify(formData) и 'data.param: JSON.stringify(formData). url переменная всё равное не появляется.

Comment: консоль.лог после объявления formData че выводит?

Comment: Когда заполняю форму и кликаю сабмит выводит все переменные в консоль.
curr:"1"
prev:"1"
sum:"1"
uri:"electricity"

Comment: data: {param: JSON.stringify(formData)},